# Выход за границу подмассива двумерного массива

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Согласно пункту  [[expr.add], 7.6.6/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4) стандарта языка C++, если у нас есть указатель `p`, который указывает на `i`-тый элемент некоторого массива из `n` элементов, и есть целочисленное значение `j`, то указатель `p + j` указывает на `i + j`-тый элемент в том случае, если `0 <= i + j <= n`; в противном случае, поведение программы не определено.

Таким образом, поведение следующего кода не определено:

```
int arr[2];
int *pi = arr + 3; //UB
```

Однако, что произойдёт, если мы "выйдем за пределы" подмассива двумерного массива? Пример:

```
int arr[2][2];
int (*p)[2] = arr;
int *pi = *p;
pi = pi + 3; //UB?
```

Указатель `p` указывает на первый элемент массива `arr`, т.е. на массив из двух элементов типа `int`. Указатель `pi` указывает на первый элемент массива из двух элементов типа `int`. В выражении `pi + 3` мы выходим за пределы массива из двух элементов типа `int`, хотя всё ещё находимся внутри массива `arr`.

Вопрос 1. Является ли выражение `pi + 3` с точки зрения стандарта языка неопределённым поведением или нет?

Вопрос 2. Является ли корректным следующий код:

```
int arr2[1];
int *pi2 = arr2 + 1;
*pi2; //OK?
```

Меня интересует строка `*pi2;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На счет (1), в стандарте четко написано, что это неопределенное поведение.

То, что под-массивы идут в памяти подряд, означает что это скорее всего будет работать на практике, но это остается неопределенным поведением.

На счет (2) полной ясности нет, но в любом случае лучше так не делать.

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52727307/2752075) высказали мнение, что такое разыменовывание имеет тот же статус, что и разыменовывание нулевого указателя. Про которое тоже [непонятно](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232), разрешено ли оно, если результат не используется или от него только берется адрес.

Answer (score 1):

Двумерный массив это 2 массива в одном, т. е. это одна последовательность.

Для массива `int arr[2][2]` - arr[0] является указателем на первый элемент. Сам массив имеет `4` элемента, так что

```
 int* p = arr[0];
  p += 3;
```

вполне нормально, так как `p` указывает на четвертый элемент

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос 2 - нет. В массиве только 1 элемент.

Вопрос 1 - массив выделяется одним куском, как что это нормальный указатель.

Только у вас в самом начале неверно: `0 <= i + j <= n`. Для массива из `n` элементов `0 <= i + j < n`.

Comment: Либо в Draft'е ошибка, либо так и парвда можно, и это не UB. Автор вопроса не ошибся.