# Можно ли обращаться к многомерным массивам как к одномерным?

Tags: c++, массивы

Насколько я помню, в C можно без проблем обращаться к многомерному массиву(NxM) по указателю: `a[i*M+j]`.

Доступна ли такая опция в C++?

В качестве примера приведу мой ответ, который и заставил меня задуматься об этом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1197648/176064

```
for (int index1 = 0; index1 < N*M; ++index1) {
    int i = index1 / M;
    int j = index1 % M;
    if (A[i][j] >= 0) { // A[0][index1] ?
    // ...
```

Интересует, можно ли в нём избавиться от вычисления подындексов(деления) или лучше не надо?
Если тут UB, оптимизатор имеет полное право превратить цикл в бесконечный(полагая, что всегда `index1 < M`)
А если нет, можно было бы избежать и деления, и глупых ошибок(которую я таки допустил), как деление на N вместо M =)

Comment: https://ideone.com/kVyC1Z ну в целом можно.

Comment: Вопрос в том, не вызовет ли это проблем. Есть ли гарантия от языка, что массив плотно упакован в памяти?

Comment: @vp_arth, имеется в виду одномерный массив, т.е. выделенный кусок памяти? вроде как да - он плотно упакован

Comment: Определитесь - обращаться по указателю или обращаться к массиву. И полноценный пример не помешал бы.

Comment: Нельзя, это UB по стандарту. Это обсуждалось тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1163691, например

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выход за границу подмассива двумерного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795463/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: Двумерный массив упакован плотно, но обращаться к нему как к большому одномерному нельзя по другим причинам.

Comment: Из кандидата на дубликат: `На счет (2) полной ясности нет`... А можно внести ясность `UB or not UB?` =)

Comment: imho если язык (С++) заставляет думать о таких вопросах, то пользоваться им точно не стоит

Comment: @avp, считаете, что в Си обращение с многомерным массивом как с одномерным — не UB? :)

Comment: @wololo, в топку те компайлеры (вместе с их создателями), в которых это не так

Comment: `Из кандидата на дубликат: На счет (2) полной ясности нет... А можно внести ясность UB or not UB?` Недавно наткнулся на любопытный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924659). Возможно, вам будет интересно :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В C/C++ есть только одномерные массивы. Но элементами одномерного массива помимо всего прочего также могут быть массивы. Таким образом N-мерный массив — это одномерный массив, элементами которого являются `N-1`-мерные массивы.

[dcl.array/note-1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#note-1):

> [*Note 1*: An array can be constructed from one of the fundamental types (except void), from a pointer, from a pointer to member, from a class, from an enumeration type, or **from an array of known bound**. — *end note*]

Также смотрите [dcl.array/example-4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#example-4):

> `int x3d[3][5][7];`
> declares an array of three elements, each of which is an array of five elements, each of which is an array of seven integers.
>
> `int x3d[3][5][7];`
> объявляет массив из трёх элементов, каждый из которых является массивом из пяти элементов, каждый из которых является массивом из семи элементов типа `int`.

Между элементами массива нет никаких "пропусков". Непосредственно за `i`-тым элементом массива следует `i+1`-ый. [dcl.array/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#6):

> An object of type “array of `N` `U`” consists of a **contiguously allocated** non-empty set of `N` subobjects of type `U`, known as the elements of the array, and numbered `0` to `N-1`.

Таким образом, даже если элементами массива являются массивы, они расположены в памяти непрерывно один за другим. Оператор `sizeof`, применённый к массиву, возвращает размер элемента массива, умноженный на количество элементов в массиве. Никакой возможности вставить лишний байт между элементами массива просто нет. [expr.sizeof/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#2):

> ... When applied to an array, the result is the total number of bytes in the array. This implies that the size of an array of `n` elements is `n` times the size of an element.

---

Теперь рассмотрим код:

```
int arr[2][10];
int* p = &arr[0][0];
p = p + 11//UB???
```

После строки `int* p = &arr[0][0];` указатель `p` указывает на первый элемент массива из десяти элементов типа `int`.
После строки `p = p + 11;` указатель `p` вроде бы должен указывать на второй элемент **другого** массива из десяти элементов (мы ведь знаем, что наши массивы расположены подряд), но с точки зрения стандарта языка — это неопределённое поведение. Наращивать/уменьшать указатель на элемент массива можно в строго определённых пределах. [expr.add/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4):

> When an expression `J` that has integral type is added to or subtracted from an expression `P` of pointer type, the result has the type of `P`.
>
> — If `P` evaluates to a null pointer value and `J` evaluates to `0`, the result is a null pointer value.
>
> — Otherwise, if `P` points to an array element `i` of an array object `x` with `n` elements ([dcl.array]),80) the expressions `P + J` and `J + P` (where `J` has the value `j`) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element `i+j` of `x` if `0≤i+j≤n` and the expression `P - J` points to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element `i−j` of `x` if `0≤i−j≤n`.
>
> — Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Как видите, никаких послаблений для многомерных массивов здесь нет.

---

Компиляция современным компилятором программы, содержащей выход за пределы подмассива многомерного массива в  `constexpr`-выражении заканчивается ошибкой. Например, для следующего кода:

```
constexpr int arr[2][10] = {};
constexpr int ind = 10;
constexpr int res = *(&arr[0][0] + ind);
```

g++ [выводит](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b69c981633cf10c9) ошибку:

> error: array subscript value '10' is outside the bounds of array type 'const int [10]'

---

В языке C выход за границы подмассива массива также приводит к неопределённому поведению. В черновике стандарта языка приводится такой пример. Если объявлен массив `int a[4][5]`, то выражение `a[1][7]` вызывает неопределённое поведение. `n1570, J.2 Undefined behavior / 1`:

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
> ...
> — An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression `a[1][7]` given the declaration `int a[4][5]`) (6.5.6).

---

Если очень хочется работать с N-мерным массивом как с одномерным, и при этом очень сильно хочется не нарушать стандарт языка, то *наверное* (я не уверен наверняка), можно проделать такой трюк:

```
const int rows = 2;
const int cols = 10;
int arr[rows][cols];

unsigned char* p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&arr);
for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; ++i)
    reinterpret_cast<int&>( p[i * sizeof(int)] ) = some_value;
```

Здесь мы рассматриваем двумерный массив, как одномерный массив объектов типа `unsigned char`. Так делать можно потому, что любой объект типа `T` также является массивом из `sizeof(T)` элементов типа `unsigned char`. [basic.types.general/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types.general#4):

> The *object representation* of an object of type `T` is the sequence of `N` `unsigned char` objects taken up by the object of type `T`, where `N` equals `sizeof(T)`.

Ни нарушения требований по выравниванию, ни нарушения strict aliasing в приведённом коде, насколько я понимаю стандарт, не происходит. Но выглядит это всё как-то неэстетично.

---

P.S. На мой взгляд, UB при доступе к N-мерному массиву как одномерному — это просто недоработка/баг в стандарте. Ибо запрещать выходить за границы подмассивов массива — какое-то насилие над здравым смыслом :) К тому же похоже, что все существующие компиляторы обрабатывают данное UB одинаково: ничего не "ломается" при оптимизации и работает как и задумано.

P.P.S. У функций `memcpy()`, `memset()` нет проблем с обработкой многомерных массивов, ибо переданный им указатель на объект любого типа они рассматривают как указатель на первый элемент массива с элементами типа `unsigned char`.

Comment: *`"Ибо запрещать выходить за границы подмассивов массива — какое-то насилие над здравым смыслом :)"`* -- люто плюсую