# почему при увеличении адреса на 11 массива с записью "a" он увеличивается на 44??? вместо положенных 11 как при записи "a[0]" и "a[0][0]"?

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Недавно начал учить Си, в коде урока было следующее

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
int a[3][4] = { {1, 2, 3, 4} , {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);         // число строк
int m = sizeof(a[0])/sizeof(a[0][0]);   // число столбцов
 
int *final = a[0] + n*m - 1;    // указатель на самый последний элемент
for(int *ptr=a[0], i=1; ptr<=final; ptr++, i++)
{
    printf("%d \t", *ptr);
    // если остаток от целочисленного деления равен 0,
    // переходим на новую строку
    if(i%m==0)
    {
        printf("\n");
    }
}   
return 0;
}
```

тут указано

```
int *final = a[0] + n*m - 1;
```

что значит указатель final должен получить адрес последнего элемента двумерного массива, так оно и происходит. Но я решил проверить работает ли это со всеми способами указания адреса массива в указатель - ну т.е.

- a;
- a[0];
- &a[0][0];

с последними двумя вопросов нет, они увеличивают адрес согласно коду ниже на 11 - как и должно быть, но вот в первом варианте адрес увеличивается на все 44, чего быть не должно по идее.
Вопрос почему так происходит, и что более интересно как??? Если все они начинаются с одного адреса.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

int a[3][4] = { {1, 2, 3, 4} , {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12} };
int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);         
int m = sizeof(a[0]) / sizeof(a[0][0]);

printf("size of a = %d\n", sizeof(a));
printf("size of a[0] = %d\n", sizeof(a[0]));
printf("size of a[0][0] = %d\n", sizeof(a[0][0]));

printf("n = %d m = %d\n\n\n", n, m);

printf("address a = %p\n", a);                      //адрес первого элемента массива
printf("address a[0] = %p\n", a[0]);                //адрес первого элемента массива
printf("address a[0][0] = %p\n\n\n", &a[0][0]);     //адрес первого элемента массива

int* fin = a + n * m - 1;                           //(увеличивается не на 11 адресов а на 44 хотя начальный адрес у всех одинаковый)
int* fin1 = a[0] + n * m - 1;                       //адрес последнего элемента массива
int* fin2 = &a[0][0] + n * m - 1;                   //адрес последнего элемента массива

printf("fin: address %p \t value %d\n", fin, *fin);             //(увеличивается не на 11 адресов а на 44 хотя начальный адрес у всех одинаковый)
printf("fin1: address %p \t value %d\n", fin1, *fin1);          //адрес последнего элемента массива
printf("fin2: address %p \t value %d\n\n\n", fin2, *fin2);      //адрес последнего элемента массива

int* ptrd = a;
int diff = fin - ptrd;
printf("fin - ptrd = %d\n\n\n", diff);

for (int* ptr = a[0], i = 1; ptr <= fin2; ptr++, i++)
{
    printf("i = %d   ptr = %p   %d   ", i, ptr, *ptr);
    
    if (i % m == 0)
    {
        printf("\n");
    }
}

printf("\n\n");

for (int* ptr = a[0], i = 1; ptr <= fin; ptr++, i++)
{
    printf("i = %d   ptr = %p   %d   ", i,  ptr, *ptr);

    if (i % m == 0)
    {
        printf("\n");
    }
}

printf("\n\n\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: int занимает 4 байта в данном случае, поэтому и 44.

Comment: `a + 11 == &a[0] + 11 == (char*)&a[0] + 11*sizeof(a[0]) == (char*)&a[0] + 11*4*sizeof(int) == (char*)&a[0] + 44*sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @wololo, по-моему, Вы немного напутали. `11*4` это же уже и есть `11*sizeof(int)`, а так у Вас получается, что к адресу прибавляется `44*sizeof(int) == 44*4 == 176`, вместо 44 как указал ТС.

Comment: @wololo, подскажите, возможно я в виду малого опыта в программировании не понимаю этого - но откуда берется приведение типа к char если изначально я объявлял массив типа int?

Comment: @V-Mor, `a[0]` имеет тип `int [4]`, поэтому `sizeof(a[0]) == 4 * sizeof(int)`. Вот почему `... + 11*sizeof(a[0]) == ... + 11*4*sizeof(int)`. `вместо 44 как указал ТС` ТС имел ввиду, что 44 раза прибавляется `sizeof(int)`, т.е. прибавляется `44 * 4 == 176` байт. Ну, и собственно [пример](https://rextester.com/ZNRJE17069) — все адреса одинаковые.

Comment: @ReijiAkkerman преобразование к `char*` написал я ;). Приведённый пример показывает равенство _адресов_, но **не** цепочку преобразований, которая происходит при вычислении выражения `a + 11`. Приведение к типу `char*` нужно, чтобы при арифметике указателей увеличение адреса происходило на заданное количество _байтов_, а не `sizeof(какой_то_тип)`. Тип `char` всегда занимает один байт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Арифметика указателей строится на том, что для

```
type * p
```

увеличение `p` на 1 означает переход к следующему элементу, т.е. увеличение значения на `sizeof(type)`.

В `ina a[3][4]` тип `a` - указатель на `int[4]`, так что в

```
 int* fin = a + n * m - 1;
```

к адресу `a` прибавляется `11*sizeof(int[4])=11*16=176`, т.е. в байтах - смещение на 176 байт, в `int`'ах (`fin` - указатель на `int`) - на `176/4=44`.

Comment: Проверил на других числах - логика работает, но почему "a" определяется как указатель если я определяю ее как массив?

Comment: @ReijiAkkerman потому что в Си массив - это указатель на первый элемент массива.

Comment: Потому что что такое `type[]`? Массив типа `type`. Так что в `int[][]` что выступает типом массива? `int[]`...

Answer (score 3):

#### Арифметика указателей

К указателям можно прибавлять, вычитать целочисленные значения. Смысл таких операций состоит в следующем.

Если `P` — указатель, который указывает на `i`-тый элемент массива из `n` элементов (или гипотетический элемент, следующий непосредственно за последним элементом массива), и `j` — некоторое целочисленное значение, то указатель `P + j` указывает на `i+j`-тый элемент массива (или гипотетический элемент, следующий непосредственно за последним элементом массива), при условии, что `0 <= i+j <= n`, в противном случае поведение программы не определено.

Также указатель `P - j` указывает на `i-j`-тый элемент массива (или гипотетический элемент, следующий непосредственно за последним элементом массива), при условии, что `0 <= i-j <= n`, в противном случае поведение программы не определено.

В приведённом коде

```cpp
int arr[2];
int* p0 = &arr[0];
int* p1 = p0 + 1;
```

указатель `p0` указывает на элемент массива `arr` с индексом `0`, а указатель `p1` указывает на элемент массива `arr` с индексом `1`.

Каждый элемент массива `arr` занимает `sizeof(int)` байт (обычно четыре байта). Хоть мы и прибавляем к указателю единицу, но в байтах, его значение увеличилось на `sizeof(int)` байт.

Это особенность арифметики указателей. Если указатель `p` имеет тип `T*`, то результат выражений `p + j` и `p - j` есть указатель «модифицированный» на `j * sizeof(T)` байт.

---

Похожим образом, с учётом размеров типа, вычисляется разность двух указателей.

Если указатели `P` и `Q` указывают на `i` и `j`-тый элементы одного и того же массива (или гипотетический элемент, следующий непосредственно за последним элементом массива), то результат выражения `P - Q` есть знаковое целочисленное значение, равное `i - j`, и имеющее тип `ptrdiff_t` (определён в заголовочном файле `<stddef.h>`).

Если `P` и `Q` не указывают на элементы одного и того же массива (или гипотетический элемент, следующий непосредственно за последним элементом массива) или величина `i-j` не представима типом `ptrdiff_t`, то поведение программы не определено.

В приведённом коде

```cpp
int arr[2];
int* p0 = &arr[0];
int* p1 = &arr[1];
ptrdiff_t diff = p1 - p0; //1
```

значение `diff` равно `1`. Однако, разница между указателями `p1` и `p0` в байтах равна `sizeof(int)` (обычно четыре). Это особенность арифметики указателей.

---

Если некоторый объект не является массивом, то для целей арифметики указателей он считается массивом, состоящим из одного элемента.

```cpp
int obj;
int* p = &obj;
//OK, obj считается массивом из одного элемента. 
//Указывать на гипотетический элемент за последним можно.
p = p + 1;
//А вот получить значение гипотетического элемента нельзя.
obj = *p; //Поведение не определено.
```

#### Массивы и указатели

Массив — это самостоятельная сущность. Массив не эквивалентен указателю на свой первый элемент.

Оператор `sizeof`, применённый к массиву, возвращает размер массива в байтах, но не размер указателя на первый элемент массива.

```cpp
int arr[7];
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(arr));      //7 * sizeof(int)
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(&arr[0]));  //sizeof(int*)
```

---

Пусть есть массив из `n` элементов типа `T`.

Оператор взятия адреса `&`, применённый к такому массиву, возвращает *указатель на массив из `n` элементов типа `T`*, т.е. указатель имеет тип `T (*)[n]` Но оператор взятия адреса, применённый к первому элементу массива, возвращает указатель на `T`, т.е. указатель имеет тип `T*`.

Указатель на весь массив и указатель на первый элемент массива представляют одинаковый *адрес*, но имеют разный *тип*. Это напрямую влияет на арифметику указателей, т.к. она зависит от *размера типа*, на который указывает указатель.

```cpp
int arr[7];
int (*p_arr)[7] = &arr;
int* p_int      = &arr[0];

p_arr = p_arr + 1; //Добавили sizeof(arr) == 7 * sizeof(int) байт.
p_int = p_int + 1; //Добавили sizeof(int) байт.
```

---

В некоторых ситуациях массив может быть неявно преобразован в указатель на свой первый элемент.

Например, если массив участвует в арифметике указателей, то он неявно преобразуется в указатель на свой первый элемент.

```cpp
int arr[2];
int* p1 = arr + 1;
ptrdiff_t diff1 = p1 - arr;  //1
ptrdiff_t diff0 = arr - arr; //0
```

`int* p1 = arr + 1` — массив `arr` неявно преобразован в указатель на свой первый элемент (с индексом ноль), следовательно `arr + 1` — это указатель на второй элемент (с индексом один) массива `arr`.
`ptrdiff_t diff1 = p1 - arr` — массив `arr` снова неявно преобразован в указатель на свой первый элемент, следовательно разность `p1 - arr` — это разность между указателями на элементы одного и того же массива с индесами `1` и `0` соответственно, следовательно результат выражения `p1 - arr` — это `1`.
`ptrdiff_t diff0 = arr - arr` — опять же массив `arr` преобразуется в указатель на свой первый элемент.

#### Многомерные массивы

`k`-мерный массив, `k > 1` — это **одномерный массив**, элементами которого являются `k-1` мерные массивы.

```cpp
int arr[7][4][3];
```

В приведённом коде `arr` — это одномерный массив из `семи` элементов типа `T1`, где `T1` — это одномерный массив из `четырёх` элементов типа `T2`, где `T2` — это одномерный массив из `трёх` элементов типа `T3`, где `T3` — это `int`.

`arr` имеет тип `int [7][4][3]`.
`arr[0]` имеет тип `int [4][3]`.
`arr[0][0]` имеет тип `int [3]`.
`arr[0][0][0]` имеет тип `int`.

---

С учётом всего написанного выше ваш код

```cpp
int a[3][4] = { {1, 2, 3, 4} , {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};

&a[0][0] + 11;
a[0]     + 11;
a        + 11;
```

работает следующим образом.

Выражение `&a[0][0]` имеет тип `int*`. Выражение `&a[0][0] + 11` означает к указателю `int*`, указывающему на объект `arr[0][0]`, прибавить `одиннадцать` раз `sizeof(int)` байт.

Выражение `a[0]` имеет тип `int [4]`, т.е. это массив. Так как к массиву прибавляется целочисленное значение, то массив неявно преобразуется к указателю на свой первый элемент, т.е. к указателю `int*`. Таким образом, выражение `a[0] + 11` означает к указателю `int*`, указывающему на объект `arr[0][0]`, прибавить `одиннадцать` раз `sizeof(int)` байт.

Выражение `a` имеет тип `int [3][4]`, т.е. это массив. Так как к массиву прибавляется целочисленное значение, то массив неявно преобразуется к указателю на свой первый элемент, т.е. к указателю `int (*)[4]`. (да, элементами массива `a` являются массивы, а не `int`'ы). Таким образом, выражение `a + 11` означает к указателю `int (*)[4]`, указывающему на объект `arr[0]`, прибавить `одиннадцать` раз `sizeof(int[4]) == 4 * sizeof(int)` байт.

#### Про выход за границу массива

В начале ответа сказано, что если выражение `P + j`, где `P` — указатель, а `j` — целое число не указывает на элемент массива (или гипотетический элемент за последним элементом массива), то поведение программы не определено.

Приведённый код содержит неопределённое поведение:

```cpp
int a[3][4] = { {1, 2, 3, 4} , {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
a        + 11; //Поведение не определено.
```

Массив `a` содержит ровно `три` элемента типа `int [4]`, следовательно выражение `a + 11` не указывает ни на элемент массива `a`, ни на гипотетический элемент за массивом, следовательно поведение программы не определено.

Более того, код ниже также содержит неопределённое поведение:

```cpp
int a[3][4] = { {1, 2, 3, 4} , {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
&a[0][0] + 11; //Поведение не определено.
a[0]     + 11; //Поведение не определено.
```

Выражение `&a[0][0]` указывает на первый элемент массива `arr[0]`, состоящего из `четырёх` элементов типа `int`, следовательно выражение `&a[0][0] + 11` не указывает ни на элемент массива `arr[0]`, ни на гипотетический элемент за массивом, следовательно поведение программы не определено.

Да, мы знаем, что непосредственно за массивом `arr[0]` следует массив `arr[1]`, а за ним следует массив `arr[2]`, однако, стандарт языка не делает никаких послаблений для такого случая.

Здесь на сайте было сломано немало копий в обсуждениях допустимости выхода за подмассивы многомерного массива. Однозначного ответа нет. Основных позиций две:

1. Стандарт суров, но это стандарт. Выходить за границы подмассивов многомерного массива при арифметике указателей нельзя и точка.
2. Так как мы знаем, что многомерный массив — это, по сути, большой одномерный массив, и все существующие компиляторы корректно обрабатывают выход за подмассивы многомерного массива, то так делать можно. А если завтра выйдет компилятор некорректно обрабатывающий выход за границы подмассивов, то его нужно немедленно удалить, авторов компилятора расстрелять.

Связанный вопрос: [Можно ли обращаться к многомерным массивам как к одномерным?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1197662)

#### Про `printf` и спецификаторы преобразования

С помощью спецификаторов преобразования вы обещаете передать функции `printf` аргумент определённого типа. И вы **обязаны** выполнить данное обещание. Если вы этого не делаете, то стандарт языка со своей стороны вам больше ничего не обещает — поведение программы не определено.

```cpp
printf("size of a = %d\n", sizeof(a));
```

Спецификатор преобразования `%d` говорит, что должен быть передан аргумент типа `int`, но оператор `sizeof` возвращает значение беззнакового целочисленного типа `size_t`. Поведение программы не определено. Используйте спецификатор `%zu` для вывода значений типа `size_t`.

---

```cpp
printf("address a = %p\n", a);
printf("address a[0] = %p\n", a[0]);
printf("address a[0][0] = %p\n\n\n", &a[0][0]);
```

Спецификатор преобразования `%p` говорит, что должен быть передан аргумент типа `void*`, но ни один из передаваемых аргументов (ни `a`, ни `a[0]`, ни `&a[0][0]`) не имеет указанный тип, и не приводится неявно в данном конкретном случае к указанному типу. Поведение программы не определено. Используйте явное приведение типа: `(void*)a`, `(void*)a[0]`, `(void*)&a[0][0]`.

Связанный вопрос: [printf and pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9056328).

Статья на cppreference.com о функции `printf` с большой табличкой по спецификаторам преобразования: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf.