# Указатель на указатель на первый элемент массива

Tags: c++

Хотел попробовать сделать указатель на указатель на первый элемент массива:

```
#include <iostream>
  
int main()
{
        int a[3] {};
        int **aa = &a;

        return 0;
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
test.cpp:6:13: error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[3]’ to ‘int**’ in initialization
    6 |  int **aa = &a;
      |             ^~
      |             |
      |             int (*)[3]
```

Comment: `&a` — это указатель на _массив_, а `&a[0]` — указатель на _первый элемент массива_. Почитайте [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248532). Возможно, будет вам интересен.

Comment: или вот так `int (*aa)[3] = &a;`

Comment: Не знаю зачем, но: `T array[Sz]; T* ptr = array; T** ptr2ptr = &ptr;`

Answer (score 2):

Первый элемент массива - `a[0]` - имеет тип `int`.

Значит, указатель на него имеет тип `int*`:

```
int * aa;
```

Получить адрес можно, применив оператор `&`. Итого:

```
int * aa = &a[0];
```

Теперь ищем *указатель на указатель* -

```
int **aaa = &aa;
```

и понимаем, что таких указателей может быть множество - поскольку может быть множество указателей на первый элемент массива.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
  
int main() {
    int a[3] {99, 2, 3};
    int *aa = a;
    int **aaa = &aa;
    std::cout << aaa << std::endl;
    std::cout << *aaa << std::endl;
    std::cout << **aaa << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```