# Пустая строка в условии

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, память

Хочу вывести слово если строка пустая. Вот так работает:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        char q[]{'\0'};

        if(!q[0])
                std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

А вот так нет:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        char q[]{'\0'};

        if(!q)
                std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Почему?

Comment: 1) Оператор `!` ожидает получить значение типа `bool`. 2) Массив может быть неявно преобразован в указатель на свой первый элемент. 3) Указатель может быть неявно преобразован в тип `bool`, причём если указатель указывает на объект, то он будет преобразован в `true`. 4) Итого, здесь `!q` массив `q` неявно преобразован в указатель, затем указатель неявно преобразован в `true`, затем оператор `!` преобразует `true` в `false`. 5) Предвещая некоторые вопросы в будущем, оставлю ссылку [на этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248532). Возможно, вам будет интересен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что `q` усть массив, по сути - **адрес** первого элемента. А поскольку первый элемент - каким бы он ни был - **всегда существует** и имеет адрес, то `q` - всегда имеет ненулевое значение. А `!q`, соответственно, нулевое, т.е. "ложь"...