# нужна помощь с генерацией чисел С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Генерация трехзначных чисел:

```
char symb [] = { '1','2','3' }; 
for (int i = 0; true; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3 ; j++)
    {
      cout << symb[rand() % 3];       
    }       
    cout << endl;
}
```

Как сделать так что бы эти числа не повторялись?
Что бы каждый раз выводилось новое число, пока не закончатся все возможные комбинации.

Comment: тут есть примерно то, что тебе нужно
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Comment: Трёхзначные числа, состоящие только из указанных цифр? Их немного ,всего 27

Comment: ну это же к примеру

Comment: ОК,  про шаффл хороший совет дали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ideone.com/Fn2DsA

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

constexpr const char chs[] = "123";
constexpr unsigned n = sizeof chs - 1;

struct s3 { char s[3]; } all[n*n*n];

constexpr void build_all()
{
  for (unsigned q=0, i=0; q<n; ++q)
    for (unsigned w=0; w<n; ++w)
      for (unsigned e=0; e<n; ++e, ++i)
      {
        all[i].s[0] = chs[q];
        all[i].s[1] = chs[w];
        all[i].s[2] = chs[e];
      }
}

int main()
{
  build_all();

  random_shuffle(begin(all), end(all));
  for (auto &x : all) printf("%.3s\n", x.s);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: решил увеличить с 3 до 10 :                                                                                                                 constexpr const char chs[] = "1234567890";
constexpr unsigned n = sizeof chs - 1;

struct s10 { char s[10]; } all[n * n * n * n * n * n * n * n * n * n];
пишет что размер массива превышает допустимый. подскажите как быть

Comment: @homer, 10**10 - это больше 9 ГБ данных. Тебе точно нужно столько чисел во всех возможных порядках?

Comment: так точно, сэр!

Answer (score 2):

https://ideone.com/Bh1nUH

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
  char chs[] = "123";
  constexpr unsigned n = sizeof chs - 1;
  bool used[n][n][n] = {};
  constexpr unsigned nnn = sizeof used;
 
  printf("%u %u\n", n, nnn);
 
  for (int q = 0, i; q < nnn; ++q)
  {
    while (used[0][0][i = rand() % nnn]);
    used[0][0][i] = true;
    printf("%c%c%c\n", chs[i/n/n%n], chs[i/n%n], chs[i%n]);
  }
 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Не гарантируется истинность выражения `sizeof(bool) == 1`. 2) Поведение программы не определено из-за [выхода за границы подмассива многомерного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1197662).

Comment: @wololo 1. Исправляется заменой на `n*n*n`. 2. Ну это странно... Везде так делают, я даже в старой книге читал, что так можно :)

Answer (score 2):

> решил увеличить с 3 до 10

Если нужны не все числа, то: https://ideone.com/tFz6d4 (возможны лидирующие нули)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  set <unsigned long long> used;
    
  for (unsigned q=0; q<100; ++q)
  {
    unsigned long long x;
    while (!used.insert(x = (((unsigned long long)rand() << 16 | rand()) << 16 | rand()) % 10000000000).second);
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(10) << x << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `((unsigned long long)rand() << 16 | rand()) << 16 | rand()` Как вы лихо склеиваете три числа, возвращаемые функцией `rand` в одно число. В VS функция `rand` возвращает [16-битные целые](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/rand-max?view=msvc-160). Хоть склейка даёт 48-битные целые, но тесты показывают, что количество таких попарно различных чисел равно `2**31`. Т.е. начиная с некоторого момента, числа начинают повторяться. Т.к. `2**31` существенно меньше, чем `10**10-1`, то приведённый код не может перебрать все целые из отрезка `[0; 10**10-1]` (по крайней мере в VS).

Comment: @wololo, упс.. А как правильно? PS: потому на 16 и сдвигаю, что 16-битные.